# Creating a second cassandra node to replicate whats on Amazon EC2 node

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

Say my Amazon EC2 instance has:

local ip: 172.31.1.1
   external ip: 54.1.1.1

I've added a "seeds" setting to Amazon EC2 instance, as 172.31.1.1 (I hope thats right).

I've got another new node in our local network (behind a firewall), I've set the seeds to 54.1.1.1, but it won't join the cluster. It says "handshaking" and then fails to connect. (even though I can telnet to 54.1.1.1 on port 7000)

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Review the [Firewall port access](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.2/reference/dse_firewall_ports)
2. Check out the `listen_address` and `broadcast_address` in `cassandra.yaml`. For details see [cassandra.yaml docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html?pagename=docs&version=1.2&file=#cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html)